# Seeing shaded boxes show up on PowerBI report via Apple PDF Preview

Tags: pdf, powerbi

We have a report that we generate on a monthly basis via PowerBI to PDF. When we view the report via a web browser like Firefox, we can see the visualizations normally, with proper shading. If we view the report via the built-in Apple PDF Previewer, it creates these odd boxes around some of the figures as if it's unable to render the shadow. Any way to get rid of this or is it just a limitation of the Apple PDF Previewer?
[Correct view via FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFGl3.png)
[Incorrect view via Apple PDF Previewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q73kX.png)

Tried other browsers, all react the same way as Firefox.

Comment: That's a bug in Apple Preview, the shadow is generated by drawing a sold rectangle through a soft mask (an image SMask) and Acrobat can only render that correctly if the Current Transformation Matrix is the identity ([1 0 0 1 0 0]). I'm aware that the bug has been reported to Apple, at least once that I know of, and potentially several times over a number of years. It seems likely Apple have no interest in fixing the problem, you'll need to find a way to make the PDF files that works for Apple if this is a problem for you.